# Why is the coefficient very large (>1) when log(outcome)?

Tags: fixed-effects-model

[Link to data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y9hLXbkFdw-qf5ofZQXWgugjuXHhgYxN/view?usp=sharing)

Background story: I'm trying to find out how being a grandparent affects working hours. The endogenous variable is `grandparent` (1 if the individual is a grandparent and 0 if not), and its instrument is `child1_female` (1 if the individual's first child is female). The outcome is log(`work_hour`), weekly working hours. I'm trying to use instrumental 2SLS with year fixed effects added, controlling for age. Here is my code:

```
iv <- feols(log(workhour)~age|year|grandparent~child1_female, sample, panel.id=~id+year)
```

However, the coefficient for `grandparent` is horrendously large: $-1.818$.

I'm trying to find out why. Please help me explain this given the context from the data. How can I locate the problem in the data?

Comment: How do you compute the log of work hours for the zero values??

Comment: @whuber NA. This is intensive margin.

Comment: I have no idea what "intensive margin" might mean, but I do know that removing these data from your dataset will bias your results.

Comment: @whuber For your reference: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/what-is-the-difference-between-intensive-margin-and-extensive-margin-in-labor-ec

Comment: Thank you.  But what does that have to do with the statistical issues you are asking about?  Once again, how do you take the log of zero?

Comment: @whuber they become NA, like I said before. This is a standard procedure in labor economics.

Comment: I seriously doubt that -- I am confident no labor economists are taking logarithms of zero seriously -- but perhaps it depends on how you treat NA values in your model.  If you won't tell us, it will be difficult to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @whuber I AM TELLING YOU: IT'S NA. If you still doubt that, take a look at this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0014292121001598

Comment: Let me try it like this: "NA" is in itself meaningless.  We all know you can't take the log of zero.  The presence of zeros in your data therefore is problematic for several reasons.  One concerns their interpretation: should they be considered valid observations or not?  If not, then why do you present them in your data sample for us to consider?  Second, if they are valid, then how exactly are they represented and modeled in your analysis?  Calling them "NA" doesn't answer that question.  The third is that you evidently have weird results, so you *ought* to investigate this situation.